# Inserting Logo on Envelope

Tags: envlab

I'm using `envlab` package to create envelopes, and would like to insert a logo into the return address. I followed package documentation instructions, but am seeing no results. Any clue what should be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you want more control over your envelopes, you can use the following.

Geometry creates an envelope sized page whose text area is the printable area (more or less).  Flowfram creates fields for the addresses relative to the lower left-hand corner of the text area.  The return address is the same on every page.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9.5in,paperheight=4.125in,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
% logo (align centers)
\newsavebox{\logo}
\savebox{\logo}{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}}
% create address fields
\newflowframe{2.5in}{1in}{0.5\textwidth}{\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-1in}
\newstaticframe{2.5in}{1in}{0pt}{\dimexpr \textheight-1in}[return]
\begin{staticcontents*}{return}
\usebox{\logo}\hspace{\fboxsep}%
\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\depth-0.5\height}% geometric center
  {\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 2.5in-\fboxsep-\wd\logo}
Name\\
Street\\
City, State Zip
\end{minipage}}\vfill\null
\end{staticcontents*}
% start addresses
\begin{document}
\rule{2.5in}{1in}\newpage
To Name\\
To Street\\
To City, State Zip
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple TikZ solution. Note that you will have to TeX this twice in order to place the text and logo correctly. TikZ writes information to the `.aux` about the positions the elements of the page -- the second TeX run allows the information to be used.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Adjust the size of the envelope here
\usepackage[papersize={9.5in,4.25in},margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

%% No logo
%% \mkenv[<other return address>]{Address\\to\\whom\\sent}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mkenv}{+O{Default\\address\\here} +m}{%
    \newpage
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[below right,text width=3in,align=flush left] at 
        (current page.center) {#2};
        %% Change the (0.25in,-0.25in) to adjust position of return address
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[below right,text width=3in,align=flush left] at 
        ($(current page.north west)+(0.25in,-0.25in)$) {#1};
}

%% With logo
%% \mkenvL[<optional\\return\\address>]{<To\\whom\\sent}[<optional graphic>]
\NewDocumentCommand{\mkenvL} {+O{Default\\Return\\Address} +m 
        +O{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}}{% Default graphic
    \newpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[below right,text width=3in,align=flush left] at 
            (current page.center) {#2};
        %% Change the (0.25in,-0.25in) to adjust position of return address
        \node[below right] (A) at ($(current page.north west)+(0.25in,-0.25in)$) {#3};
        \node[anchor=west,text width=3in,align=flush left] at (A.east) {#1};    I'm 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\mkenv{First line\\Second line\\Third line}

\mkenv[x1\\x2\\x3]{First line\\Second line\\Third line}

\mkenvL{First line\\Second line\\Third line}%[<Non-default graphic here>]

\end{document}
```